# Keyboard interrupt handler causing system to freeze

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, interrupt-handling

This is my first stack overflow post (long time lurker), so sorry in advance if this question isn't well worded.

I'm trying to make a kernel module to emulate keypresses when a user presses a button, and using http://www.staerk.de/thorsten/My_Tutorials/Writing_Linux_kernel_modules as an example.

It does simulate a keypress when the module is initialized, but when I send an interrupt and try to run the same code the entire virtual machine freezes.

Here's snippits of my code:

```
static void got_char(struct work_struct *taskp) 
{
    struct myprivate *myp = container_of(taskp, struct myprivate, task);

    if ((myp->scancode == 0x01) || (myp->scancode == 0x81))
    {
        printk ("You pressed Esc !\n");
        println ("Pressed ESC ! \n");
        ch=65;
        tty_insert_flip_char(tty, ch, 0);
        con_schedule_flip(tty);
    }
    else if (myp->scancode == 0x1D) {
        printk ("You pressed Ctrl!\n");
    }
    else {
        printk("Scancode = %d", myp->scancode);
    }
}

irq_handler_t irq_handler(int irq, void *dev_id, struct pt_regs *regs)
{
    static int initialised = 0;
    /*
    * Read keyboard status
    */
    myp->scancode = inb(0x60);

    if (initialised == 0) {
        INIT_WORK(&myp->task, got_char);
        initialised = 1;
    }
    else {
        PREPARE_WORK(&myp->task, got_char);
    }
    schedule_work(&myp->task);

    return (irq_handler_t) IRQ_HANDLED;
}

/* Helper method to print stuff to the terminal */
static void println(char *string)
{
    tty = current->signal->tty;
    (tty->driver->ops)->write (tty, string, strlen(string));
    ((tty->driver->ops)->write) (tty, "\015\012", 2);
}

/* Initialize the module and Register the IRQ handler */
static int __init keybrd_int_register(void)
{
    myp = kmalloc(sizeof (*myp), GFP_KERNEL);

    int result;
    /* Request IRQ 1, the keyboard IRQ */    
    result = request_irq (1, (irq_handler_t) irq_handler, IRQF_SHARED, "keyboard_stats_irq", (void *)(irq_handler));

    /* Test simulating keypress */
    println ("inserting A ! \n");
    ch=65;
    tty_insert_flip_char(tty, ch, 0);
    con_schedule_flip(tty);

    if (result)
        printk(KERN_INFO "can't get shared interrupt for keyboard\n");

    return result;
}
```

Everything works as expected, except for when ESC is pressed, then my entire system just freezes and I have to restart my VM.

I've looked through many posts and forums online and can't find an answer.
Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is println() defined?  Try commenting it out in your task handler.

Comment: Whoops, forgot to add that in. println() is a method that prints things on the terminal. I had that in earlier to test things with, edited the original post so the code that's failing is there instead.

Comment: Just to diagnose, comment-out that call to println() in the task handler to see if the hang goes away.  It could be a re-entrancy/recursion issue.  printk() works fine because it goes to another kernel component.

Comment: Wow I can't believe that fixed it, thanks a lot. Can I upvote your comment or anything?